# unsubscribe to an Observable created by of

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

When I create an observable and I am done with it I unsubscribe it directly

```js
const data$ = this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').subscribe(res => {
  console.log('live', res);
  data$.unsubscribe(); // <---- works fine
});
```

But say if I create an Observable using `of` and try to do the same

```
const obs$ = of(1).subscribe(e => {
  console.log('test', e)
  obs$.unsubscribe(); // <--- Problem while creating Observable by of
});
```

Whats different between these 2 observables?

Comment: `of` completes synchronously, so you are attempting to call `obs$.unsubscribe` before the assignment to `obs$` has been made. The HTTP observable will complete asynchronously - after `obs$` has been assigned.

Comment: I think this makes perfect sense. Can you post it as an answer so that, I can mark it

Comment: `subscribe` functions should be *pure* and not reference variables outside the scope of the function. Both your examples are *impure* functions with side effects. While your question is specific to observables, if you're doing this elsewhere in your source code you'll continue to run into bugs. Here's a tutorial on the topic: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/pure-versus-impure-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be import Subscription and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

```
import { Observable, Subscription, of } from "rxjs";
private subscription$: Subscription;

this.subscription$ = of(1).subscribe(e => {
  console.log('test', e)
});

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Update: What I understand is http request is an observable that potentialy have incoming value in the future and `of` simply create a list of observable

And from @cartant comment

> of completes synchronously, so you are attempting to call
>   obs$.unsubscribe before the assignment to obs$ has been made.

Comment: thats a way of doing. My question is more of a why.

Comment: I think you cant unsubscribe immidiately in this case. This is recommend way from a lot of developer to manual subcribe and unsubcribe observable

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one observable in your component that would be the easiest scenario for unsubscribing by the following way:

`ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
}`

the more complex scenario is having multiple observables, at that moment you will not to push each observable while subscribing in `subscriptions: Subscription[]` and while destroying do unsubscribe all added subscriptions in the array `ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }`

or you can use that [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-take-until-destroy)

Comment: Why do I have to use package ? You can unsubcribe by using takeWhile

Comment: @TonyNgo Do you mean by defining a flag indicates when should you unsubscribe or not?

Answer (score 0):

For ensuring unsubscription in a component, I would recommend creating a `Subject` which emits in `ngOnDestroy()` like this:

```js
destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}
```

And adding a `takeUntil` on each `Observable` in the component:

```js
myObs$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  tap(stuff => doStuff())
).subscribe();
```

This way you avoid polluting things with loads of unnecessary `Subscription` variables.